# How much on-chain activity is to and from exchanges?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, exchanges

Are there any data services which provide metrics that show how much of the transactions on the Bitcoin blockchain are to and from exchanges?

Answer (score 0):

Blockchain.com show charts of "The total USD value of trading volume on major bitcoin exchanges."

Doubtless there are other publishers of equivalent data.